# Password reset links sometimes don't work

Tags: routes, authentication-authorization

I've got this problem where once in a while, when a user uses the one time password link, instead of going to the password reset page, it takes them to the home page. Whenever this happens, in the error log I see this:

> Path: /user/reset/[user ID]. Drupal\Core\Http\Exception\CacheableAccessDeniedHttpException: This route can only be accessed by anonymous users. in Drupal\Core\Routing\AccessAwareRouter->checkAccess() (line 118 of /var/www/html/web/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Routing/AccessAwareRouter.php).

I've found answers to why this can happen, but I haven't found an answer for why it happens *sometimes*. Do you have any suggestion on how to resolve it? Would it be a bad thing to make the form available to authenticated users?

Comment: Are the users authenticated when it occurs?

Comment: No. They wouldn't be. They are not logged in, submit a form to receive a one-time link to their email. I don't think it is cached credentials either. I made it happen with a user that hadn't logged in before.

Comment: Are there any authentication-related modules installed?

Comment: Maybe some login redirect module? Or something custom happening on hook_user_login?

Comment: There is a login redirect module, but this was happening before I added that. I'll look at the authentication modules tomorrow. Thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Checking on the authentication modules: I've got an oauth2 module which is necessary for connecting to some other sites, and I've got the External Authentication module which used to be necessary, but I don't think is used currently. I can try removing that. Of course the problem is that I only ever see this problem every couple of weeks, and I can't manually reproduce it!